# Magento Paypal Express guest checkout on mobile browser

Tags: magento, paypal, express-checkout

I am using Paypal express checkout and enable guest checkout option. It's working fine on desktop but when try from mobile browser Paypal not give option to pay as guest checkout. Paypal force to create Paypal account. what should I change at Magento level in parameter of express checkout?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?